# Enabling two finger scrolling in Ubuntu gnome 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo, scrolling

How to enable two finger scrolling in Ubuntu gnome 14.04 . The feature is seen enabled in dconf Editor, but it is not working. Also there is no option for scrolling in the mouse and touchpad settings.

When the command  xinput; dmesg | grep pnp is typed in the terminal the following output is obtained.(I am copying the terminal output as I cant upload the screenshot image)

karthik@LenovoU41:~$ xinput; dmesg | grep pnp

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Keyboard     id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]

    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Keyboard     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]

[    0.895283] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 7 devices
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Comment: I cant show the screenshot because i dont have enough reputation to post an image.

Comment: I do not need screenshots. Please try again `dmesg | grep pnp` and give FULL output.

Comment: karthik@LenovoU41:~$ dmesg | grep pnp
[    0.895283] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 7 devices
karthik@LenovoU41:~$

Comment: It looks like your touchpad is not supported by kernel yet. You can upgrade your kernel to get new drivers by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid` and reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your touchpad is not supported by the current kernel.

You can upgrade linux kernel to get new drivers by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot.